# How can I enforce certain parameter values for Flutter widgets of a given type?

Tags: flutter, dart

For instance, I am working on an app with many screens, so I am creating lots of `Scaffold`s and `AppBar`s.

Say my design spec says that "the appbar title should be centered always, on all platforms", i.e. I want the `centerTitle` argument to `AppBar` to always be `true`.

I could wrap `AppBar` with a custom widget `MyAppBar` and always set `centerTitle` to `true`, but

1. This implies a lot of boilerplate to expose all of the other `AppBar` properties
2. This requires annoying maintenance to keep up with framework changes to `AppBar`

Is there an option better than "just try to remember to set it everywhere you create an `AppBar`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a custom `MyAppBar` widget that always center the title is the correct solution.

But the premise that is has a lot of boilerplate/hard to maintain is false.

You don't **need** all `AppBar` properties. Only expose those that are relevant to your app.